# display dynamic tags in meta tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

On my `index.php`, i am trying to implode an array of meta tags loaded from MYSQL db. I am trying to echo it in `<meta>` tag. But it shows the last tag only. Why is it so?

**html**

```
$meta_t=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tags");
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($meta_t,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $meta_tags=array();
    $meta_tags[]=$row1['tag_name'];
    $comma_separated = implode($meta_tags);
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GripOffers</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $comma_separated;?>">
```

Comment: `$meta_tags=array();` <-- move that to outside of your loop

Comment: `$meta_tags=array();` <-- that, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Three corrections:**

1) Define array outside loop. Your code every time defines a new array. Therefore, you are getting only latest value.

2) Move `implode()` outside loop. You need to `implode()` whole array, not the latest iteration value.

3) `implode()`: First parameter missing, I placed `,`.

**Corrected code:**

```
$meta_t=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tags");
$meta_tags=array();
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($meta_t,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 $meta_tags[]=$row1['tag_name'];
}
$comma_separated = implode(', ', $meta_tags);
```

Answer (score -1):

> set $commaa_separated value after complete while loop

```
$meta_tags=array();
$meta_t=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tags");
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($meta_t,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $meta_tags[]=$row1['tag_name'];

       }
        $comma_separated = implode($meta_tags);
    ?>
```

Comment: 1. Incorrect 2. Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) 3. Please do not abuse the formatting tools

Comment: i know when you post this comment at time i also update my answer with expatiation  please check and remove down vote

Answer (score -1):

> Issue 1 : You can set `$meta_tags` in `while` loop so it can be initialize all time.
>   Issue 2 : Implode `$comma_separated` array variable is not proper in loop.

```
<?php
    $meta_t=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tags");
    $meta_tags=array();
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($meta_t,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $meta_tags[]=$row1['tag_name'];
    }
    $comma_separated = implode($meta_tags);
?>
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)